# Translate SQL to JPQL (SELECT NEW and "AS" keyword)

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jpql

I'm newbie in JPQL, but I need to translate a simple SQL request to JPQL:
SQL:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  t.column1 + t.column2 as coefficient 
FROM 
  practice.People as t
ORDER BY coefficient
```

I can't use that native query because I don't know how to map it to class :(
I try to use this JPQL query:

```
  SELECT NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight, 1)
  FROM 
    People AS c
  ORDER BY c.age;
```

How can I change "1" to coefficient in this request? The only solution I imagined is just use:

```
SELECT NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight, c.age + c.height)
FROM 
  People AS c
ORDER BY c.age + c.height;
```

But I don't think it's the right solution :( What should I do?

### Infragile, thanks for your answer!

But it still doesn't work :(
It's a result of applying your answer to my code:

```
public List<PersonWell> findWell(People person){
    String queryString = 
            "SELECT\n"
            + "NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight, c.speechspeed, "
            + "ABS(c.age - :age) + ABS(c.height - :height) + ABS(c.weight - :weight) + ABS(c.speechspeed - :speechspeed)) AS p \n" 
           +"FROM "
            + "People AS c\n"
           +"ORDER BY p.compatibility DESC";
    Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("age", person.getAge());
    query.setParameter("height", person.getHeight());
    query.setParameter("weight", person.getWeight());
    query.setParameter("speechspeed", person.getSpeechspeed());
    List<PersonWell> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

Ans this's an answer from a glassfish server:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT
NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight, c.speechspeed, ABS(c.age - :age) + ABS(c.height - :height) + ABS(c.weight - :weight) + ABS(c.speechspeed - :speechspeed)) AS p 
FROM People AS c
ORDER BY p.compatibility DESC], line 4, column 9: invalid navigation expression [p.compatibility], cannot navigate expression [p] of type [entities.PersonWell] inside a query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this doesn't work for you?

```
SELECT NEW entities.PersonWell(c.peopleId, c.name, c.age, c.height, c.weight, c.age + c.height) AS p
FROM 
  People AS c
ORDER BY p.coefficient;
```

Where `p.coefficient` is field where is your value  `c.age + c.height` put using `PersonWell` constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But, it is a pity, it doesn't work :(
I'll append my question to describe my problem. Please, see details.